# ObjectMapper not printing correct json in file

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson, objectmapper

```
ArrayList<ActionOutput> res = manager.getRes();
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
objectMapper.writeValue(new File(args[1]), res);
```

I expect my outputFile to look EXACTLY like this:

```
[
  {
    "key1": "value",
    "key2": [],
    "key3": null
  },
  {
    "key1": "value",
    "key2": [],
    "key3": null
  }
]
```

but it looks like this:

```
[ {                   <-- I need a newline after [
  "key1" : "value",
  "key2" : [ ],
  "key3" : null
}, {                  <-- I need a newline after },
  "key1" : "value",
  "key2" : [ ],       <-- no whitespace in empty array: [] instead of [ ]
  "key3" : null       <-- no whitespace after keys: "key3": null instead of "key3" : null
  } ]                 <-- I need a newline after }
```

How can I achieve this?
I tried also to use pretty printer on objectMapper, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize indentation options of the [`DefaultPrettyPrinter`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultPrettyPrinter.html) using its methods `indentObjectsWith()` and `indentArraysWith()`. Both expect an instance of [`Indenter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.7.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultPrettyPrinter.Indenter.html) interface. One of its implementations shipped with Jackson is [`DefaultIndenter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.7.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultIndenter.html).

```
DefaultPrettyPrinter printer = new DefaultPrettyPrinter();
printer.indentObjectsWith(new DefaultIndenter());
printer.indentArraysWith(new DefaultIndenter());
```

When we have customized the `DefaultPrettyPrinter`, `ObjectMapper` should be instructed to use it for serialization.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setDefaultPrettyPrinter(printer);
```

Finally, produce the JSON:

```
ArrayList<ActionOutput> res = manager.getRes();

mapper
    .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
    .writeValue(new File(args[1]), res)
```

Here's a small demo illustrating that indentations would be set correctly.

Consider the following POJO:

```
public class ActionOutput {
    private String key1;
    private List<String> key2;
    private String key3;
    
    // all-args constructor, getters
}
```

*Serialization example:*

```
List<ActionOutput> actions = List.of(
    new ActionOutput("value", List.of(), null),
    new ActionOutput("value", List.of(), null)
);
        
String jsonRes = mapper
    .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
    .writeValueAsString(actions);
    
System.out.println(jsonRes);
```

*Output:*

```
[
  {
    "key1" : "value",
    "key2" : [ ],
    "key3" : null
  },
  {
    "key1" : "value",
    "key2" : [ ],
    "key3" : null
  }
]
```